# Al generar apk (hecha en ionic) no conecta con api

Tags: android-studio, ionic, ionic-framework

Desarrollé mi app en ionic v. 6.18.1, lo estoy usuando con el frame Angular.

Genero mi app para Android con capacitor de la siguiente manera

*npx cap add android*

Me genera el directorio Android, el cual abro con Android Studio. Genero mi apk e instalo.
Pero no tengo conexión a base de datos, no funciona mi API.

```
getMesasF(id){
return this.http.get('http://MI-IP/api/mesas2.php?id='+id);
}

getInfoU(id){
return this.http.get('http://MI-IP/api/mesas3.php?id='+id);
}
```

Mis dos api al ejecutar *ionic serve* funcionan perfecto, pero en la apk no funcionan. ¿Alguna ayuda que puedan brindarme? De antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué errores tienes por la consola del navegador o los logs del servidor?

Comment: podras encontrar la solución a esto en el siguiente hilo.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Answer (score 1):

Me pasó y acabo de solucionarlo, tuve que ir al archivo:

> 'network_security_config'

que se me creó automáticamente, el cual apuntaba a *localhost*, y cambiarlo por la IP donde estaban mis servicios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]